# How to convert and fix this query for codeigniter?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have this MYSQL query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM store_product 
LEFT JOIN store_promo_product ON store_product.store_product_id = store_promo_product.store_product_id
LEFT JOIN store_promo ON store_promo.store_promo_id = store_promo_product.store_promo_id 
JOIN product ON product.product_id = store_product.product_id
WHERE store_product.store_id = 338 and store_promo_product.store_product_id=52
```

While i know how to convert it to **`codeigniter`** Active Record using Join syntax, the problem is that sometimes i can have few `"store_product_id"` from the same store so the query will return the product details + promo details twice or more (depends how much promos i have for the same product). I am looking for away to return only ONE product (because it is the same product) with two promos (because they are different promo sales) ..

Hope i explained my self.
even pure `mysql` will do if possible of course.

Comment: Look into `GROUP BY`

Comment: well, Consider that i want only ONE product with all of its promos..(remember i can have a few promos per one product)

Comment: Looked into GROUP BY. I tried to GROUP BY store_product_id but now it will return the product with only one promo.

Comment: @Dror Try using `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT promo_field)` dont remove the `GROUP BY`

Answer (score 0):

I ended up splitting the function into two functions which seemed to work.